# why the output screen is white, in jetpack compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm writing the code using jetpack compose to preview the UI. When I run the app the output screen of the app is white its seems it's blank.
I'm trying to create UI of netflix, but the output screen of the app is white. Sometimes, showing the app is closed.

```kotlin
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.Image
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Spacer
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.size
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.width
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Person
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Search
import androidx.compose.material3.Icon
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.res.painterResource
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import com.example.netflix.R
import com.example.netflix.ui.theme.NetflixTheme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .background(Color.Black)
            ) {
                TopAppSection()
                NetflixContentChooser()
            }

        }
    }
}

@Composable
@Preview
fun TopAppSection() {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(Color.Black),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
                        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {
        // Netflix icon
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.netflix),
            contentDescription = "icon",
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(60.dp)
                .padding(10.dp)

        )
        Row {
            Icon(
                imageVector = Icons.Default.Search,
                contentDescription = "Search icon",
                modifier = Modifier.size(24.dp),
                tint = Color.White
            )

// Spacer to add some space between icons
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(16.dp))

// User icon
            Icon(
                imageVector = Icons.Default.Person,
                contentDescription = "User icon",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(24.dp)
                    .padding(end = 6.dp),
                tint = Color.White,


                )
        }
    }
// Spacer to add some space between icons



}

@Composable
@Preview
fun NetflixContentChooser(){
    Row (
        modifier= Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(Color.Black),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween

    ){
        Text(text = "Series", color =Color.White )
        Text(text = "Films", color =Color.White )

        Row {
            Text(text = "Categories", color =Color.White )
            Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_drop), contentDescription ="icon drop")
        }


    }
}
```

This is error I'm getting

I' trying to create UI of netflix, but the output screen of the app is white. Sometimes, showing the app is closed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add Surface and Column

```
Surface(
    color = Color.Gray,
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
){
    Column(
        verticalArrangement =  Arrangement.SpaceAround,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        modifier = Modifier
            .wrapContentSize()
    ) {
        Row(
            modifier= Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .background(Color.Black),
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
        ){
            Text(text = "Series", color =Color.White )
    Text(text = "Films", color =Color.White )

    Row {
        Text(text = "Categories", color =Color.White )
        Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_drop), contentDescription ="icon drop")
    }


}
```

}

Comment: Please add some more information to your answer, explaining not only the *how* but also the *why*.

Comment: Using Surface for background Color and Modifier to cover the full screen. Using Column for vertical arrangement and inside Row for horizontal arrangement.

Answer (score 0):

Create a composable and call your composable in it and then call App Composable in set content:

```
@Composable
fun App() {
    Column {
        TopAppSection()
        NetflixContentChooser()
    }
}
```