# After starting the app why the output screen is white, in jetpack compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

1

I'm writing the code using jetpack compose to preview the UI. When I run the app the output screen of the app is white its seems it's blank. I'm trying to create UI of netflix, but the output screen of the app is white. Sometimes, showing the app is closed.

```kotlin
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.Image
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Spacer
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.size
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.width
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Person
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Search
import androidx.compose.material3.Icon
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.res.painterResource
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import com.example.netflix.R
import com.example.netflix.ui.theme.NetflixTheme
import org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants.HorizontalAlignment

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .background(Color.Black)
            ) {
                TopAppSection()
                NetflixContentChooser()
                FeaturedMovieSection()
            }

        }
    }
}


@Composable
@Preview
fun TopAppSection(){
    Row (modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .background(Color.Black),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        )
    {
        Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.netflix), contentDescription ="netflix logo",Modifier.size(20.dp))
    Row (
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically

    ) {
        Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.search_svgrepo_com), contentDescription ="search", modifier = Modifier.padding(12.dp).size(20.dp))

        Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.profile_svgrepo_com), contentDescription ="profile",Modifier.size(20.dp) )
    }
    }
}

@Composable
@Preview
fun NetflixContentChooser(){
    Row (
        modifier= Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(Color.Black),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically

    ){
        Text(text = "Series", color =Color.White )
        Text(text = "Films", color =Color.White )

        Row {
            Text(text = "Categories", color =Color.White )
            Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_drop), contentDescription ="icon drop")
        }


    }
}

@Composable
@Preview
fun FeaturedMovieSection(){
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(Color.Black)
            .padding(bottom = 60.dp)
        ,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.pngegg), contentDescription ="Movie" )
        Row(modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(top = 60.dp, start = 80.dp, end = 40.dp)
            ,
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween


        )
        {
            Text(text = "Drama", color = Color.White)
            Text(text = "Thriller", color = Color.White)
            Text(text ="Entertainer", color = Color.White)
            Text(text = "Hollywood" , color = Color.White)

        }
    }

}
```

This is error I'm getting

I' trying to create UI of netflix, but the output screen of the app is white. Sometimes, showing the app is closed.[image: The app is white, its seems blank]

I want to create netflix UI for android using jetpack compose, but a white screen is appeared

Comment: Hey, I think you posted the same question twice? [why the output screen is white, in jetpack compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77941206/why-the-output-screen-is-white-in-jetpack-compose)

Answer (score 0):

Create a composable function App() and call all your composable in this function and then call this app() composable in your set content field. This will fix the issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).